# FFMPEG API -- How much do stream parameters change frame-to-frame?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I'm trying to extract raw streams from devices and files using ffmpeg.  I notice the crucial frame information (Video: width, height, pixel format, color space, Audio: sample format) is stored both in the AVCodecContext and in the AVFrame.  This means I can access it prior to the stream playing and I can access it for every frame.

How much do I need to account for these values changing frame-to-frame?  I found https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/demuxing__decoding_8c_source.html#l00081 which indicates that at least width, height, and pixel format may change frame to frame.

- Will the color space and sample format also change frame to frame?
- Will these changes be temporary (a single frame) or lasting (a significant block of frames) and is there any way to predict for this stream which behavior will occur?
- Is there a way to find the most descriptive attributes that this stream is possible of producing, such that I can scale all the lower-quality frames up, but not offer a result that is mindlessly higher-quality than the source, even if this is a device or a network stream where I cannot play all the frames in advance?

The fundamental question is: how do I resolve the flexibility of this API with the restriction that raw streams (my output) do not have any way of specifying a change of stream attributes mid-stream.  I imagine I will need to either predict the most descriptive attributes to give the stream, or offer a new stream when the attributes change.  Which choice to make depends on whether these values will change rapidly or stay relatively stable.

Comment: Don't ask questions tagged [tag:c] or [tag:c++] without referring to code you have. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to add to what [@szatmary says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32445302/4726410), the typical use case for stream parameter changes is adaptive streaming:

- imagine you're watching youtube on a laptop with various methods of internet connectivity, and suddenly bandwidth decreases. Your stream will automatically switch to a lower bandwidth. FFmpeg (which is used by Chrome) needs to support this.
- alternatively, imagine a similar scenario in a rtc video chat.

The reason FFmpeg does what it does is because the API is essentially trying to accommodate to the common denominator. Videos shot on a phone won't ever change resolution. Neither will most videos exported from video editing software. Even videos from youtube-dl will typically not switch resolution, this is a client-side decision, and youtube-dl simply won't do that. So what should you do? I'd just use the stream information from the first frame(s) and rescale all subsequent frames to that resolution. This will work for 99.99% for the cases. Whether you want to accommodate your service to this remaining 0.01% depends on what type of videos you think people will upload and whether resolution changes make any sense in that context.

Does colorspace change? They could (theoretically) in software that mixes screen recording with video fragments, but it's highly unlikely (in practice). Sample format changes as often as video resolution: quite often in the adaptive scenario, but whether you care depends on your service and types of videos you expect to get.

Comment: Thanks for this best answer.
The ambiguity of the ffmpeg api seems a little unfortunate; I'm looking into gstreamer instead for now.

Answer (score 0):

Usually not often, or ever. However, this is based on the codec and are options chosen at encode time. I pass the decoded frames through swscale just in case.